# please check this sql code for my aggregate function to update a table in access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have having problem in running this sql for aggregate update in access. what I trying to do is update the "pointbalance" in table [employee database] from substrating the sum of "nbrpoint" in table 2 which the sume is group by the "SysID". it return a error message as follow " Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression. I am stuck on this for half day, can anyone tell me what is wrong with my sql coding? here we go:

```
Update [employee database] 
Set [pointbalance] =[pointbalance] - t2.nbrpointsum
From [employee database]
Inner join (select [sys ID],[entered],sum(nbrpoint) as nbrpointsum 
            from [temp call log entries]
            group by [Sys ID]) as t2
On t2.[sys ID] = [employee database].[SysID]
```

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Is it Mysql or Access?

Comment: MySQL doesn't use `[]` around names, so this isn't MySQL.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that describes the actual problem you're having or question you're asking. *Please check this sql code* is not a problem description or question. Your title should be clear enough about it's meaning to be useful to a future reader who sees it among other search results. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS Access has a different syntax for the UPDATE query. The syntax follows this sequence:

```
UPDATE <table1>
INNER JOIN <table2>
ON <some conditions>
SET <update expression>;
```

It is different to yours (which BTW is a MS SQL syntax by the looks)

You need to re-write your query to this:

```
Update [employee database] 
Inner join (select [sys ID],[entered],sum(nbrpoint) as nbrpointsum 
            from [temp call log entries]
            group by [Sys ID]) as t2
On t2.[sys ID] = [employee database].[SysID] 
Set [employee database].[pointbalance] = [employee database].[pointbalance] - t2.nbrpointsum
```

Comment: Actually MySQL can use the `INNER JOIN` in `UPDATE` statements. OP's posted syntax is neither compliant in MySQL nor MS Access.

Comment: I didn't claim it was a MySQL syntax. It is a SQL Server syntax

Comment: Actually the current program I am using is Access, and the syntax you provided is what I am looking for, and it works for me, thank you so much.